# Panic not seen in this scenario

Tags: go

I see a panic

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch <- 1
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}

fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox058504389/main.go:10 +0x60
```

I believe, go detects that main routine is blocked on the write and since there is a block that happens while writing to unbuffered channel, the read snippet will never be reached and we see the panic. Why don't we see the issue in below code and why is go not panicking

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch := make(chan int)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        <-ch 
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Whereas if in the working snippet, if I change `<-ch` i.e. channel read to `ch<-`, which is a write, I do see the error. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: that example panics as expected: https://play.golang.org/p/4EB3eVveHFL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both examples this is a behaviour of channels. There are 2 types of channel, buffered and unbuffered.

Buffered channels have some capacity to store items within the channel. Like a buffer.

Unbuffered channels do not have a place to store items in the channel, this means that before anything can be sent into / written to an unbuffered channel, there much be something read to read from it. This means you must have a goroutine on each end of the channel, one ready to send, and one ready to receive.

In the first example:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch <- 1
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

You have 1 goroutine (the main go routine). This single goroutine attempts to write a value to the channel `ch <- 1`, but there's no another goroutine ready to receive the value *at exactly the same time!* You've got a read from the channel in the function `fmt.Println(<-ch)` but this is executed **after** the write, but the write cannot succeed because there's no read ready at the same time as the write. You need 2 goroutines!

In the next example:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch := make(chan int)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        <-ch 
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

When tested in the playground this also panics. This is because you've created a second goroutine with `go func() {... }` that attempts to read a value from the channel, but there's nothing sending a value *at exactly the same time*. So all the goroutines are blocked and there's a panic.

One thing to note about this example, is that if the channel `ch` is closed, with `close(ch)` before the read happens, the read will **always** succeed. It will be able to read the zero value (in this case `0`) from the channel.

As you've pointed out, adapting the above example to have a write in the anonymous function `ch<-` will also panic, *because there's no second routine ready to receive the value at exactly the same time!*

Here is a simplified, adapted working version, showing you need a read and a write on an unbuffered channel to happen at the same time.

https://play.golang.org/p/gNzgA9Vosm6